# Browser client hung on a Tornado - Celery request

Tags: celery, tornado

I am testing Tornado - celery - RabbitMQ integration. So, I took [this](https://github.com/mher/tornado-celery/tree/master/examples) code from GitHub & modified it to get better understanding. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and here's what I have done so far:

```
Installed Tornado and working great on its own.
Installed RabbitMQ (apt-get install rabbitmq-server).
Installed Tornado Celery (downloaded and unzipped the tar file).
Executed python -m pip install tornado-celery
Borrowed 2 example python files from above Github Repo and modified it.
```

My Tasks snippet code (myTornadoTasks.py) is:

```
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime

from celery import Celery
from celery import task

celery = Celery("myTornadoTasks", broker="amqp://")
celery.conf.CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get('CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND', 'amqp')

@celery.task
def add(x, y):
    return int(x) + int(y)

    ..... some more code 

@celery.task
def error(msg):
    raise Exception(msg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   celery.start()
```

I start the tasks using celery worker -A myTornadoTasks --concurrency=4. Here everything works fine.

My Tornado Celery snippet code (myTornadoCelery.py) is:

```
from tornado import gen 
from tornado import ioloop 
from tornado.web import asynchronous, RequestHandler, Application

import myTornadoTasks

import tcelery tcelery.setup_nonblocking_producer()

class AsyncHandler(RequestHandler):
    @asynchronous
    def get(self):
        myTornadoTasks.sleep.apply_async(args=[3], callback=self.on_result)

    def on_result(self, response):
        self.write(str(response.result))
        self.finish()

... some more code

class GenMultipleAsyncHandler(RequestHandler):
    @asynchronous
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        r1, r2 = yield [gen.Task(myTornadoTasks.sleep.apply_async, args=[2]),
                        gen.Task(myTornadoTasks.add.apply_async, args=[1, 2])]
        self.write(str(r1.result))
        self.write(str(r2.result))
        self.finish()

application = Application([
    (r"/async-sleep", AsyncHandler),
    (r"/gen-async-sleep", GenAsyncHandler),
    (r"/gen-async-sleep-add", GenMultipleAsyncHandler),
])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8887)
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I start Tornado using "python myTornadoCelery.py". No Errors. I bring up a browser and enter "http://localhost:8887/gen-async-sleep-add" and the browser keeps spinning. I can see the tasks received by Celery and executed. I don't see Task ID returned etc on the browser. If I put simple print statement in the GenMultipleAsyncHandler, I don't see the execution coming back after the Yield command. I have to kill the browser. The same thing happens if I try any other Tornado Request handler. What am I doing wrong or missing?

Thanks

Comment: Does your `AsyncHandler` work? In other words, does it execute the task on Celery and return? Seems like I have exactly the same problem. I do see the task is executed but the call doesn't seem to be non-blocking!